# Git extensions not working in VSCode for only one project

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am facing a really weird issue with Visual studio code and all the Git related extensions(Specially GitLens and GitHistory). What I am seeing here is that both of the extensions are not working for a particular project that I have.

GitHistory does not show history and Git Lens `Unable to show file history. The file is probably not under source control.`. In fact, this file and entire project is under source control. All the git commands from the terminal are working as expected including `git log`, which I thought these extensions may be relying on in the background.

Also, I turned on verbose logging for git lens and it is not logging any particular problem that I can see in the console.

My VS Code and both extensions are updated to the latest version. I am not sure what else to try . Any suggestions?

Comment: How big is this project? Sometimes this happens with huge projects.

Comment: You may be right. It's a huge project. Anything that I can do to fix this?

Comment: Umm.. Try increasing limit on file watchers. On Linux it's something like systcl -p, you edit a file, increase the number to some 52k and reload. You'll definitely find it of you search for it on Google. Happens with node projects sometimes.

Comment: This is a mac and I used `sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000` to increase the max files limit. but still no luck.